# Bitrix проблема связанная с ЧПУ

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста такая проблема. Есть страница с блогом site.ru./blog/ В нем создали компонент bitrix:news и при включенном чпу при переходе на страницу новости ссылка правильная site.ru/blog/razdel/novosti-1/ но ! подгружается страница site.ru/services/index.php. Так-же если создать и другие компоненты и все это при включенном ЧПУ

Сам site.ru/services/index.php работает как нужно

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news",
    "",
    Array(
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "6",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "info",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "20",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/blog/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => Array("detail"=>"#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/","news"=>"","section"=>"#SECTION_CODE#/"),
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
        "USE_RSS" => "N",
        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N"
    )
);?><br>
```

и

```
<?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/portfolio/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/portfolio/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/services/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/services/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\??(.*)#',
    'RULE' => '&$1',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog.top',
    'PATH' => '/services/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/blog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/blog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Приложите вызов компонента  в разделе /blog/ и код файла urlrewrite.php в корне сайта

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий Добавил

Comment: вам нужно в urlrewrite.php поднять свое правило с обработкой `'CONDITION' => '#^/blog/#'` выше чем `'CONDITION' => '#^\\??(.*)#'` потому что они обрабатываются по порядку вот до вашего обработчика не доходит зато попадает в `'#^\\??(.*)#'` и отправляет вас в `/services/index.php`

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий корректно все работает при полном удалении 
#^\\??(.*)# но конечно не работает теперь тот модуль :)

Comment: так перепишите правило сами, что бы работал и модуль и ваш компонент

Comment: Приложите снимки экрана настроек ЧПУ инфоблока и компонента